# Submit buttons not working while using type image

Tags: php, html

This is a simple demonstration of my code :

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
   do this
}

<form method='POST' action="index.php">
Username : <input type='text' name='username'/>
Password : <input type='password' name='password' />
<input type='image' src='images/login.png' name='login' value='login'/>
</form>
```

The problem is that , when i use type='image' as a submit button, in Firefox and IE nothing happends. But if i use type='submit' everything works fine..

Well i dont want to display the button as a submit one, but as an image, so what im doing wrong ?

Comment: If you're willing to use JavaScript you could add an onClick form submit?

Comment: what is input type  = image ? and how could form gonna know when to submit itself ? and clicking on last input type element in form dosnt mean it will submit form

Comment: your html code is correct and works fine, @hanky answer's for the solution : wrong POST check

Comment: @wordpresser input type=image results as 2 more indexes in the `_POST` array :  `$_POST['login_x']` and `$_POST['login_y']`. Their values correspond to the (x,y) coordinate of the mouse from the top left of the picture ( = (0,0) if you press enter))

Comment: let me try that one @ Asenar . thanx for enlightening me

Comment: And, I noticed some old spam robots don't create theses 2 extra indexes, so this can be an extra check : human user will always post with x and y (even if = 0). __EDIT :__ maybe we should make test on terminal browser to see its behaviour. __EDIT2:__ I confirm, I got `login_x` and `login_y` index with lynx

Comment: I made this question , because type='image' used to work as Submit buttons , Google Chrome still supprots this method, IE and Firefox dont.

But now im using this :
<button type="submit" name='hyr' value='Hyr' ><img src="images/login.png"/></button>
and everything is working just fine , thanks a lot for you answers and for you no votes LOL, i made the question to learn from you and not to get voted haha

Comment: Dajan, see my answer who will probably answer your needs ;)

Answer (score 3):

Simply change your `if` to look for any other field in the `POST`. Image type button wont send that value.

Change:

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
```

To

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
```

Comment: care to tell how form is submitting without a submit button or js ?

Comment: lol come on, have you not heard of `<input type="image">` ? That is a submit button and does not require any JavaScript to work. That will work as a submit button by default, without having to do anything extra.

Comment: heard just a few mins ago. its never too late. thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check login, you need to check for `login_x` or `login_y` values instead of `login`, which is not created when button is an image.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['login_x'])) { 
   echo "Here I m";
}
?>
<form method='POST' action="index.php">
Username : <input type='text' name='username'/>
Password : <input type='password' name='password' />
<input type='image' src='images/login.png' name='login' value='login'/>
</form>
```

Sorry, I explained in a comment the type=image creating `_x` and `_y`, but I forgot the params  `login` does not exists in that case